# How to check if key and values are same, if same how to create new dictionary to those key value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

input:

```
 screen_map = {
   'A': 'A',   # Screen A stays as screen A
   'B': 'B1',  # Screen B maps to a new screen title Modified1
   'C': 'B1',  # Screen C maps to a new screen titled Modified1
   'D': 'D',   # Screen D stays as screen D
  }


  

import json
      from collections import Counter

      # Create the initial 1-to-1 mapping
      screen_map = {}
      for screen in screen_sequences['screen'].values:
         screen_map[screen] = screen
```

Modify the values in the `screen_map` variable in an intelligent way based on your investigation,
which should lead to a smaller number of unique values.

How to solve this?

Comment: can you please share what output you need? and more details.

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65964265/edit), and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
screen_map = {
    'A': 'A',   # Screen A stays as screen A
    'B': 'B1',  # Screen B maps to a new screen title Modified1
    'C': 'B1',  # Screen C maps to a new screen titled Modified1
    'D': 'D',   # Screen D stays as screen D
}

new = {k: v for k, v in screen_map.items() if k == v}

print(new)
{'A': 'A', 'D': 'D'}
```